# click function does not work on dynamically created element

Tags: jquery

can anyone explain why this code works:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#file").on('change',function(){
$("#selected_files_div").append("<input type='button' class='red_button'>");
$(".red_button").on('click', function(){
// do something
});
});
});
```

but this one does not work?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#file").on('change',function(){
  $("#selected_files_div").append("<input type='button' class='red_button'>");
    });
    $(".red_button").on('click', function(){
    // do something
    });
    });
```

Appending always works but click event works only in first.. case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try binding click event on parent with [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("body").on('click',".red_button", function(){
   // do something
});
```

Read more here [What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

Comment: Thank you  for reply , it works... You learn something new everyday,,